# Using the Refresh() method causes RectangleShapes to 'blink'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a simulation of CSMA/CA and I'm using four rectangle shapes from the visual basic powerpack pane. Now when I move one packet several times I want it to refresh so that the packet can be seen moving but when I use the Refresh() method in my code along with the Threading the other 3packets sort of 'blink' and it's very annoying. Any idea how I can stop the blinking? here is code for moving one of my packets(under a button):

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 6

        Refresh()
        pc4sense.Left += 25
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(30)
    Next i
    pc4sense.Location = New Point(124, 229)
```

Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This code does not provide too much information. Please, post a more significant chunk (where all the bits are properly defined; for example: what is Refresh()?).

Comment: Thats a visual basic provided method and the definition provided with it is : Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.

Comment: this code move the packet to the right side that's all the code under the button

Comment: Refresh() as you write it might be many things. In the most likely scenario an overridable method where you can write anything you want. Regarding the moving part this is clear in your code; I meant everything else (what might be provoking the blinking): how are you declaring the objects, adding/removing to the form, further actions you do in the GUI, etc. = all the relevant code.

Comment: I dragged and dropped the packets onto the form didnt instantiate them myself,for now i put just this piece of code to test it. there are picture boxes as well,about 8 of them but none of them blink just the rectangleshape from visual basic's powerpack

Comment: OK. Also, please, explain your code because there are various bits I don't quite understand: what are you trying to accomplish with the loop? Performing a "soft" movement in X? Have you included anything at all in the Refresh() method? Have you tried to just not use the Refresh method at all? pc4sense is a rectangle from powerpack?

Comment: Additionally, bear in mind that PowerPacks might not be the "cleanest approach". What geometry you want and why you cannot get it with other control?

Comment: If you open a new project, add a rectangle from powerpacks named pc4sense, a button and add your code to the click event method of the button, you would see there is no blink (= it is not the default behaviour in this situation); and this is basically what you code tells us. Can you please add more code to help us simulate your specific conditions?

Comment: u know now that u have said it i will just use a picturebox for the packets. when i put this code in a button witht the loop part i.e to just move the packet once off none of the other packets blink even with the Refresh() method and yes I just used the Refresh() method as it was no overriding. letme switch to a different control thanx

Comment: You are welcome. If you still have problems (and in future posts), please be as clear and provide as much information as possible (at least, the context: method where the problematic code is called), such that the help can be provided quickly and accurately.

Comment: This problem is real enough, the PowerPack shape controls are drawn without double-buffering.  It can't be turned on either, that ruins the transparency effect that the hidden shape container uses.  They are just not done very well, this was a quicky project to get some lost functionality in VB6 back into Winforms for VB6 programmers.  Get ahead by just painting shapes yourself with the Graphics class in a Paint event handler.